# Create new threads in a for loop and pass parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

Consider this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    new Thread(() => Test(i)).Start();
}
```

The `Test(int i)` function:

```
public void Test(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=== Test " + i);
}
```

**The actual output:**

> === Test 3
>   === Test 4
>   === Test 4
>   === Test 5
>   === Test 5
>   === Test 5
>   === Test 9
>   === Test 9
>   === Test 9
>   === Test 10

as you can see some numbers are missing and some other been duplicated.

**Expected output:**

I expect to see all numbers in random order.

**Question**

Should I lock any variables/methods? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I lock any variables/methods? How can I fix this?

Your problem is with *Closure* and *Captured Variables*

Change your code as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    int tmp = i;
    new Thread(() => Test(tmp)).Start();
}
```

For more info: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx or
http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeevr/archive/2012/02/26/closures-and-captured-variable.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's an [overload of the Thread.Start method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x4c42hc) that takes a parameter. Using that, you avoid the closure:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    new Thread(o => Test((int)o)).Start(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update (for .net 4.0 onwards) : 
Instead of `for` loop, you can write a [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.100).aspx)  loop which will really take advantage of parallel processing.

```
  Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
            {
                new Thread(() => Test(i)).Start();
            });
```